# Could not build module error while importing a pod in bridging-Header using cocoapods

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I am getting the following error while importing a pod in bridging-Header using cocoa pods.

added *use_frameworks!* in podfile

```
/Users/harsha/Desktop/podTests/podTests/podTests-Bridging-Header.h:6:9: note: while building module 'DesignSystem' imported from /Users/harsha/Desktop/podTests/podTests/podTests-Bridging-Header.h:6:
#import <DesignSystem/PBDesignSystem.h>
        ^
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "/Users/harsha/Desktop/podTests/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DesignSystem.framework/Headers/DesignSystem-umbrella.h"
        ^
/Users/harsha/Desktop/podTests/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DesignSystem.framework/Headers/DesignSystem-umbrella.h:13:9: note: in file included from /Users/harsha/Desktop/podTests/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DesignSystem.framework/Headers/DesignSystem-umbrella.h:13:
#import "PBDesignSystem.h"
        ^
/Users/harsha/Desktop/podTests/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DesignSystem.framework/Headers/PBDesignSystem.h:10:9: error: 'PBDesignSystem/PBFont.h' file not found
#import <PBDesignSystem/PBFont.h>
        ^
/Users/harsha/Desktop/podTests/podTests/podTests-Bridging-Header.h:6:9: error: could not build module 'DesignSystem'
#import <DesignSystem/PBDesignSystem.h>
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/harsha/Desktop/podTests/podTests/podTests-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Comment: When you add _use_frameworks!_, you actually don't need to import the pod in the bridging header. Just do `import DesignSystem` inside your swift file whenever you need it. (I'm not sure if it's called this. You can always find all the built frameworks inside pods folder.)

Comment: When I delete use_frameworks!, and use directly from the swift file it is giving Could not build Objective-C Module.

Comment: Wait...You need use_frameworks! if you want to use directly from swift file...

Comment: Still I am getting the error  Could not build Objective-C Module.